# Best package for typesetting extremely large chess boards, with hundreds of pieces

Tags: chess

It appears that there are some extremely knowledgeable TeX chess package experts on this site.

I have need to produce nonstandard size chess boards (80 x 80 and larger), densely crowded with hundreds of pieces. Which chess package is best suited for this? The ideal package I have in mind would allow me to specify a board and position in an array style, consisting of rows like this:

```
 
 P & p & B & N & K &   & \\
 Q &   & k &   & p & b & \\
```

but much larger. Such a format would avoid the need to figure out coordinates for each piece, and also allow more flexibility in making changes to the board, if say, large chunks need to undergo a translation relative to others. But of course, I will be happy with any package capable of producing large boards.

I am using miktex, in case that matters.

Comment: Glad you asked this question, since I was looking for something similar to this about 2 weeks ago, only for a modified  interpretation using [FEN notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation).

Comment: I think FEN would also be workable for me.

Comment: A quick CTAN search wasn't very helpful. You can get the large size boards with the [diagram package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chess-problem-diagrams) but the specification of pieces is in German and the notation is clumsy: wKUi{11} means a white king (upside down) on the ith column of the 11th row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

80x80 is quite large ;-). `chessboard` allows a maximum of 26 files (files are "numbered" alphabetically and this would be difficult with larger numbers). So with `chessboard` you would have to use more than one board and glue them together. `\chessboard` understand FEN, but in this size it is rather slow:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chessboard}
\setchessboard{maxfield=t40,
               boardfontsize=8pt,               
               label=false,
               showmover=false,
               margin=false}
\begin{document}
\lineskip=0pt
\noindent
\chessboard[borderright=false,setfen=k1K3q5r/5pP]%
\chessboard[borderleft=false,setfen=k1K3q5r/5pP]%

\end{document}
```

If you want something faster and with a more specific input syntax you will have to write parser which translates your P to "PawnOnWhite" and "PawnOnBlack". E.g. along this line (beside key-val command expl3 contains quite a lot other useful command which allows you to parse a token list):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chessfss}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_rank_int
\keys_define:nn {myboard}
 {P .code:n =
  {
   \int_add:Nn \l_rank_int {1} 
   \int_if_odd:nTF{\l_rank_int}{\WhitePawnOnWhite}{\WhitePawnOnBlack}   
  },
  p .code:n =
  {
   \int_add:Nn \l_rank_int {1}
   \int_if_odd:nTF{\l_rank_int}{\BlackPawnOnWhite}{\BlackPawnOnBlack}
  },  
  %% and so on
 } 
\newcommand\FileOdd[1]{\int_set:Nn\l_rank_int{0}\keys_set:nn{myboard}{#1}}    
\newcommand\FileEven[1]{\int_set:Nn\l_rank_int{1}\keys_set:nn{myboard}{#1}}    
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\lineskip=0pt
\parindent=0pt
\FileOdd{P,P,P,p,p,P,P,P,P}\\
\FileEven{P,P,P,P,p,p,P,P,P}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your extremely informative answer! I will give things a try and report back later.

Comment: It works great!